# writing a logfile when backgroundWorker job completed

Tags: c#

I have c# application where it  displays a message on messagebox after the query is run.At the sametime I  want it to write  a logfile. This is what i tried but no luck. My logfile was empty.
It had created a empty file.

```
 private void backgroundWorker_Import_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            //Finally, loop through each row in the dataView and execute INSERT Statements against database
            int recCount = 0;
            successCount = 0;
            failedCount = 0;

            dv.RowFilter = "execute_bit IN ('1')";

            using (MySqlConnection connectionMySql = new MySqlConnection(connectionStringMySql))
            {
                connectionMySql.Open();
                MySqlCommand commandMySql = new MySqlCommand();
                commandMySql.Connection = connectionMySql;
                foreach (DataRowView rowView in dv)
                {
                    recCount++;
                    backgroundWorker_Import.ReportProgress(recCount);
                    commandMySql.CommandText = rowView["sql"].ToString();
                    try
                    {
                        successCount = successCount + commandMySql.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        //WriteToLogFile("");
                        //WriteToLogFile("");
                        **WriteToLogFile(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ", " + recCount.ToString() + "," + successCount.ToString() + "," + failedCount.ToString());
                    }**
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        failedCount++;
                    }   
                }
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker_Import_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            string msg = "";
            msg = msg + "Records successfully imported: " + successCount.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            msg = msg + "Records that failed to import: " + failedCount.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
            msg = msg + "Records excluded from import (20 minute grace-period): " + (tblVehicles.Rows.Count - successCount - failedCount).ToString();

            progressBar1.Visible = false;
            MessageBox.Show( msg, "Operation complete", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);


        }
**private void WriteToLogFile(string[] output)
            {
                StreamWriter sw = null;
                FileStream fs = null;
                string logfileFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine( "C:/luvi/logfile.txt");
                fs = File.Open(logfileFileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
                sw = new StreamWriter(fs, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                foreach (string line in output)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(line);
                }

                sw.Close();
                sw = null;
            }**
```

Comment: Is the program running successfully? Are you facing any errors?

Comment: NO error it runs and displays the message box with success and failed records count. I  need the same info displayed on logfile.

Comment: Consider the [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement when working with FileStream and StreamWriter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `File.WriteAllLines` as shown in [this topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Its' syntax is as follows:

```
public static void WriteAllLines(
     string path,
     string[] contents
)
```

In your case you would use it like so:

```
string logfileFileName = @"C:/luvi/logfile.txt";
File.WriteAllLines(logfileFileName, output);
```

Note: this overwrites the file, if you want to append them use [File.AppendAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383691.aspx).

---

You need to actually call your method aswell, which may be a problem because I do not see that in your code. In the following changes I have replaced the `string msg` for an `array`, and added those (you could also use a list and call list.Add).

```
private void backgroundWorker_Import_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string[] msg = new string[] {};
    msg[0] = "Records successfully imported: " + successCount.ToString();
    msg[1] = "Records that failed to import: " + failedCount.ToString();
    msg[2] = "Records excluded from import (20 minute grace-period): " + (tblVehicles.Rows.Count - successCount - failedCount).ToString();

    // Write to log!
    WriteToLogFile(msg);

    // Show to messagebox.
    string showmsg = msg[0] + Environment.NewLine + msg[1] + Environment.NewLine + msg[2];

    progressBar1.Visible = false;
    MessageBox.Show(showmsg, "Operation complete", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

}

private void WriteToLogFile(string[] output)
{
    string logfileFileName = "C:/luvi/logfile.txt";
    File.AppendAllLines(logfileFileName, output);
}
```

Comment: Thanks  Matthijs but i received this error `No best type found for implicitly-typed array` on  string[] msg = new[] {};

Comment: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.-         Application.Run(new Form1());

Comment: That is in your load or constructor. Deem this question to be resolved and open another, as you are now experiencing problems that have nothing to do with your initial question.

Comment: string[] msg = new string[3].. that did the work thanks Matthijs.#

Comment: Glad I could help! Creating a list rather than using an array would also be an option, it creates option for more reporting.

Answer (score 0):

it seem problem with WriteToLogFile( string[] output) method.  You are passing single string while it is expecting arrary of string.  catch block is failing it silently.